# Having a problem with concatenate not working properly when concatenating with a link

Tags: php

Hello when I used php concatenating the code with the link in phpmailer why it's does not working?

Here are the two method that I tried.

This concatenate method does not concatenate the $userverifcationCode with the link but when I copy the link and enter it, it works. But it is a hassle if you are just gonna copy it.

```
'http://localhost/Bloodlad/user/verificationForgot.php?code='.$user_verificationCode;
```

This concatenate method works but when I click the link it is echoing invalid code.

```
'http://localhost/Bloodlad/user/verificationForgot.php?code='.trim($user_verificationCode);
```

Method 1 verification code:
http://localhost/Bloodlad/user/verificationForgot.php?code= xGLNJM

Method 2 verification code:
http://localhost/Bloodlad/user/verificationForgot.php?code=SN6Wqq

[Method1&2 Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1huk.png)
This is the code for verifying the code.

```
$code = $_GET['code'];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_verificationCode=?";
      $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $code);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result=$stmt->get_result();
      $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
      $count=$result->num_rows;
      if($count > 0){
        $user_isVerified='Yes';
        $user_verificationCode="";
        $sql="UPDATE users SET user_isVerified=?, user_verificationCode=? WHERE user_verificationCode=?";
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $user_isVerified, $user_verificationCode, $code);
        if($stmt->execute()){
          echo 'You have successfuly verified your account <br>';
          echo '<a href="login.php">Click this link to login</a>';
        }
      }else{
        echo 'Invalid verification code';
      }
```

the $code is the verification code. It is located after the verificatonForgot.php?=code.

```
$mail->Body = 'http://localhost/Bloodlad/user/verificationForgot.php?code='.$user_verificationCode;
```

**The PHP version I'm using is PHP 7.4.23 / PHP 7.4.23**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode that part of the URL correctly, like:

```
$mail->Body = 'http://localhost/Bloodlad/user/verificationForgot.php?code='.rawurlencode($user_verificationCode);
```